# Do completed promises further up the chain get GC'd?

Tags: javascript, promise, garbage-collection

If you add promises to a promise chain in a long running process like this:

```
let q = Promise.resolve();
let i = setInterval(() => {
    q = q.then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("one resolved");
                resolve();
            }, 1)
        });
    });
}, 2);
```

Will the completed promises in the chain get garbage collected, or will they leak memory?

Is it safe to add to the chain by re-assigning the chain var (q) to `q = (q + nextPromise)` over a long running application? Is there a better method to create a promise based queue?

[image]

From this example it seems like it will be GC'd, but this is only over 30 seconds?

Comment: There is no long chain in your example. All the callbacks are added to the same `q` promise

Comment: If you want to make a long chain, then you should do `q = q.then(...)` and then your question would make more sense.

Comment: @Bergi thanks this is what I meant to post, updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the completed promises in the chain get garbage collected?

Yes, they're not referenced by anything - neither an outstanding asynchronous task (through the `resolve` callback) nor the global `q` variable. You can see them being collected in your debugger screenshot.

A promise created by `then` does not reference the promise on which the callback was chained. Only the callback (stored in the promise it was attached to, and even that possibly only weakly via the resolver) references the new promise's resolving capability. Once it is settled, there is no reference retained to anything.

> Is it safe to add to the chain by re-assigning the chain variable `q` to `q + nextPromise` over a long running application?

Yes, this is a totally fine pattern. Just make sure that you don't queue new chain links faster than you can resolve them :-)

Answer (score 2):

Promises are no different from any other object; they will be GC'd once there are no more references.

Until a promise is resolved, its `resolve` callback is a reference (if that reference is lost, the promise cannot be resolved, and may be GC'd).

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  The question wants to know whether it can get GCed when it's part of chain and the current promise is long since done, but others are chained into a long chain from it.  So, what we all need to know is when it's in a chain, when are references to it from descendants in the chain cleared to make it eligible for GC.  That's the real question here.